# bash script returns empty ps results, same one-liner on CLI returns correctly

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a bash init script that runs this command:

```
sudo -umyuser APPLICATION_ENV=production php script/push-server.php >> /var/log/push-server.log 2>&1 &
```

I then try to capture both pids and put them into a file:

```
echo $! > /var/log/push_server.pid
childpid=$(ps --no-heading --ppid $! | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }')
echo $childpid >> /var/log/push_server.pid
```

However, if I use the --no-heading flag it returns blank. If I run that very same ps command on the command line, it returns the proper pid number. The same happens if I modify the command a little bit like so:

```
childpid=$(ps --no-heading --ppid $! | awk '{NR>1}' | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }')
```

I've tried removing the NR, tail, adding the --no-header, and even going all the way down to just doing:

```
chidlpid=$(ps --no-heading --ppid $!)
```

and it still won't return the child pid.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not an answer, but a tip: `pgrep -P ${!}` should suffice to return the desired PID, if it exists (yet) - hypothetically more than 1, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone who jumped in to help! The answer was indeed to add a sleep n:

```
    sudo -umyuser APPLICATION_ENV=production php script/push-server.php >> /var/log/push-server.log 2>&1 &
    mainpid=$!
    echo $mainpid > /var/log/push_server.pid
    sleep 3
    childpid=$(ps --no-heading --ppid $mainpid | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }')
    echo $childpid >> /var/log/push_server.pid
    echo -n "push_server started on pid $mainpid $childpid"
    return
```

Comment: You can use `childpid=$(pgrep -P $mainpid)`

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The second time you use `$!` you actually use the pid of the echo. Save it in a variable for later use.</strike>

Above statement is not true, as @mklement0 pointed out `$!` only updated when a new background process is started.

The most likely problem therefore is the timing: maybe the child process is not forked yet by the time the script checks for the pid.

Comment: what do you mean by fails? have you tried to issue a `set -x` before so you have a detailed ouput of the script to check?

Comment: I mean it has exactly the same empty output for the child process as the other ways ive tried it with awk's 'NR>1' and ps's --no-heading

Comment: sorry, the formatting on this thing is near impossible:

`sudo -umyuser APPLICATION_ENV=production php script/push-server.php >> /var/log/push-server.log 2>&1 &`

`mainpid=$!`

`echo $mainpid > /var/log/push_server.pid`

`childpid=$(ps --no-heading --ppid $mainpid | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }')`
`echo "PID: $childpid"`
`echo $childpid >> /var/log/push_server.pid`
`echo -n "push_server started on pid $! $childpid"`

Comment: Here's what I'm getting:

`+ mainpid=28593
+ echo 28593
+ sudo -umyuser APPLICATION_ENV=production php script/push-server.php
++ ps --no-heading --ppid 28593
++ tail -1
++ awk '{ print $1 }'
+ childpid=
+ echo 'PID: '
`

Comment: geez why is the formatting so non-intuitive on here! :\

Comment: I think you're confusing `!$` - a history expansion command that returns the previous command's last token - with the special parameter `$!`, which contains the most recent *background* task's PID - two unrelated concepts. Thus, since there's only 1 background command in the OP's code, the value of  `$!` does NOT change after.

Comment: That means that by the time the `ps` is executed there is no child process of the given parent process

Comment: You changed `!$` to `$!`, but you still claim, `The second time you use $! you actually use the pid of the echo.`, which is incorrect.

Comment: You're right, I did thought that it will be reseted as well. But there's no harm in saving it anyway. Also it makes even more likely that even the original code should have worked and there's something with the monitored application.

Comment: @user3474724, I just realised that an other issue can be that the script is quicker than you and the host process did not fork the child process quick enough. So when you do the check in the console, manually you give it more time but not when you run the script. Try adding a `sleep 5` before trying to check the child pid

Comment: Yes, saving the value is good practice, but please remove the incorrect statement. Good guess re timing issue.

Comment: Fair enough, I've updated the answer to summarize what's been suggested originally and has been discussed since